# Using PHP to read from a zip file held on another server that has a secure login

Tags: php, zip

I have access to a zip file that is held on another server, and I have login details to access this.

```
ftp://someserver.com
username: someuser
password: somepassword
```

This zip file is available daily and changes daily, and is a large file (>50Mb).

I need a script on my own server that daily reads this zip file, extracts the text files from it, and saves all the CSV data to a database on my server.

Option 1 I have for this is to log in to the other server daily, download the zip file, then upload it to my own server, and then run the PHP script that reads the text files and parses the CSV data to the database.

Option 2, which I would prefer, would be to have my PHP script just read the contents of the original file, from the original server - that would cut out the need for me to daily download the file and then re-uploaded it again to my own server.

I don't know if this is possible, though, because the file is stored on the other separate server, which is also protected.

I see other questions about opening protected files, or accessing files from the same server from a protected directory, but this question relates to accessing files from a protected different server entirely.

Is this possible to do? Or will I just need to go for the longer option and upload a local copy of the zip file every day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this all fully working now.

I used:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
```

To move the file from the remote server to my own,

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($localzipfile);
$zip->extractTo($localpath);
```

And then used,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
```

To populate the MySQL database.

I now have the full process running automatically from one php script!

Comment: i am in the same situation.. data feed is in zip file to another protected server.. where they update the data zip files in daily.. i have to take those files to my server .. then read the content from the xml file.. ripping my hair..

Answer (score 0):

The Option 1 as detailed by you should be the correct approach to perform this task. Download->extract->read CSV->Save Data to your MySQL DB.

Option 2: reading a content from remote server is equivalent to downloading the content as script is being executed on your server.

Comment: The question is, though, can this be done automatically by a PHP script, or does the downloading from the remote server have to be done manually?